# Dynamically updating the nivo slider parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, nivo-slider

We want to update the nivo slider dynamically for transition type,pause time etc.We are calling a function on click event of a link.This is the function:

```
function fnSetPauseTime(navType) {
    var getSec = $('#setSliderTime').val();
    getSec = (getSec) * 1000;

    var sliderId = $('#' + IdParent).children().attr('id');
    $('#' + sliderId).attr('pauseTime', getSec);
    var transType = $('#changeTrans').val();
    //var transType = $('.controlNav').is('checked');
    var getSec = $('#setSliderTime').val();
    slideShow(sliderId, getSec, transType, navType);
}
```

This is the click event for calling the above function

```
$('.controlNav').click(function () {
    var navType = $(this).val();
    if (navType == 'thumbNav') {
        navType = 'true';
    } else {
        navType = 'false';
    }
    fnSetPauseTime(navType);
    //slideShow(sliderId, '');
});
```

This is the default slideshow function in the **nivo-slider.js** file.

```
function slideShow(sliderId, getSec, transType, navType) {
  $('#' + sliderId).nivoSlider({
    effect: 'random',
    slices: 15,
    boxCols: 8,
    boxRows: 4,
    animSpeed: 500,
    pauseTime: 3000,
    startSlide: 0,
    directionNav: navType,
    controlNav: navType,
    controlNavThumbs: navType,
    pauseOnHover: true,
    manualAdvance: false,
    prevText: 'Prev',
    nextText: 'Next',
    randomStart: false,
    beforeChange: function () {},
    afterChange: function () {},
    slideshowEnd: function () {},
    lastSlide: function () {},
    afterLoad: function () {}
  });
}
```

**ISSUE:** We are neither able to update the parameters dynamically nor do we get any error for it.It works on load of the file(i.e first time).Not sure what is the mistake or we are doing it totally wrong.Please suggest a solution for it.

Comment: What do you mean dynamically? Change behavior after it have been initialized?

Comment: Yes I change it on initialize,I call the function on click after it has been initialized.This is a template builder application where user can create **HTML** templates.Here he can choose a slideshow and set preferences to be displayed on the site.So,I need to change the parameters when he selects a option or clicks a button.

Answer (score 2):

Just destroy the node before initializing the slider and substitute it.

```
//Save the DOM node before a slider is binded to it
var slider = $('#' + sliderId).clone();

function slideShow(sliderId, getSec, transType, navType) {
   var newSlider = slider.clone(),
   var oldSlider = $('#' + sliderId);
   oldSlider.after(newSlider);
   oldSlider.remove();

   newSlider.nivoSlider({
      ...
   }   
}
```

Comment: I didn't get you exactly.Can you please elaborate a bit!!

Comment: It seems that it inits just once and the second try doesn't override the behavior so there's no `destroy` method provided either. What you're left is to remove the DOM element since the old data is bind to it and substitute it with a fresh new one and then make it a slider again.